# Can a user offer a bounty that is worth more than their own reputation?

Tags: support, bounty, reputation

The user who asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52238/wireless-keeps-cutting-out-every-several-minutes) question has offered the bounty worth 500 but their own reputation is just 314. Is it possible to offer a bounty worth more than one's own reputation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As soon as you put a bounty on a question the reputation is deducted from your total - as there are no refunds on bounties. As such the resulting "lower than posted" rep means they originally had around 800 rep prior to posting the bounty.

Comment: For example, my rep at the time of this comment is 1469.  If I put a 500 rep bounty on a question, my rep would immediately decrease to 969, as per the reason @Marco described.

Answer (score 4):

No they can't offer more bounty then they currently hold but bounty is immediately subtracted when offered. If a user has 100 reputation and they offer a +50 bounty their rep immediately decreases to +50 reputation.